# How do I set the color sequence in a filled map in PowerBI?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset of (US State, First Infection Date), so like ('UT', '04-Jan-2020') and so on for each state. I wanted to show the spread on the filled map, but I don't know how to control the color "sequencing" or whatever. Say I divided the "infection span" into 7 equally sized buckets, I could use ROYGBIV color sequence to make the map show the order of infection. But how do I use the "rank"/sequence into a color in my map? Can I get the color from a text value/RGB value in a table? (So use something like CHOOSE to convert the sequence group to a color).

What I'm aiming at creating is a map of the country and all the states filled one of the 7 colors. (so if the virus spread via 19th century methods, it would go across the ground from west to east and the west coast would be red and the middle of the country maybe green, and the east coast would be purple.)

thanks

I created a regular map, but the colors for each state are determined by some unknown algorithm. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to the color sequence. I just created a "First Infection Date" calculated column for the states, and graphing that works, but I can't control the color sequence.

Oh, I see it now.Hidden carefully under the Visual pane is a sequence of colors.
Set them to the ROYGBIV sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the formatting pane on the visual, and select the "fx" conditional formatting icon under the fill colors tab. This will allow you two set up to a three-tone gradient or a rule-based formatting.